# How to update webpack and all loaders at once?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Quite tired to update webpack and loaders manually.

Is there a way to update webpack and all loaders at one go, any existing npm lib or script?

Comment: If you use VS Code, the Version Lens plugin is awesome! https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) which allows you to set a filter

```bash
npx npm-check-updates --upgrade --filter "webpack*, *-loader"
```

Or you run it in interactive mode, so you can select which packages to update

```bash
npx npm-check-updates --format group --interactive
```

Comment: Nice it works, even propose to install found packages with other package manage as it found pnpm lock file.

Comment: Great! Glad it works! Would you mind marking this answer as accepted? Just to let others know that this issue has been resolved, thanks!